# I am using Owl Carousel - Filter on projects as per category so i want to show the category description on every category button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have category table field and project table field in db i am fetching data or project as per category ID and showing them using php codedigniter in Owl Carousel - Filter Javascript. 
below are the detail mention. include image view. [image]

**What actually i want i am trying to show the category detail under the projects on category button click**
I assign the same class to the category button and the project by concatenating the category Id and projects category Id. So when we click on button the projects having same button class are appear perfectly but it not showing the category detail while click on specific category button click. for more information i am attaching my code as well. please have look. and help me. if you understand the problem.

### my PHP Codeigniter Code is:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px; text-align: center;">
                    <div class="btn-filter-wrap">
                        <button class="btn-filter" data-filter="*">All</button> 
                        <?php $categorydetail = ""; ?>
                        <?php if (!empty($categorydata)) { foreach ($categorydata as $category) {                    
                            $categoryclass = "category".($category['id']);
                            $categoryname = ($category['shortname']); 
                            $categorydetail = ($category['detail']);
                            ?>                                       
                            <button class="btn-filter" data-filter=".<?php echo $categoryclass; ?>"><?php echo $categoryname; ?></button>
                        <?php }} ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-slick categories">
                        <?php if (!empty($projectdata)) { foreach ($projectdata as $project) {
                            $projectclass = "category".($project['categoryid']);
                            $title = ($project['title']); 
                            $detail = ($project['detail']); 
                            $image = ($project['userfile']); 
                            ?>                               
                            <div class="item view view-eighth <?php echo $projectclass; ?>">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('fassets/images/projects/'. $image);?>" />
                                <div class="mask">
                                    <h2><?= $title ?></h2>
                                    <div><?php echo (strlen($project['detail'])>50)?(substr($project['detail'],0,200).'...'):$project['detail']; ?></div>
                                    <a class="info ajax projects" href="<?php echo base_url("maincontroller/pdetail/".$project['id']);?>" >In Large</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <dir id="catdetail"><?= $categorydetail;?></dir>
                        <?php }} ?>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
```

### this is my javascript code is:

```
$(function() {           
    var owl = $('.categories').owlCarousel({
        rel: 'gal',
        width: "100%",
        initialWidth: "0",
        initialHeight: "0",
        height:"100%",
        // loop    :false,
        // margin  :10,
        // nav     :false,
        previous: "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
        next: "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>",
        close: "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>",
        current: "",
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:2
            },
            1000:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    })

    /* animate filter */
    var owlAnimateFilter = function(even) {
        $(this)
        .addClass('__loading')
        .delay(70 * $(this).parent().index())
        .queue(function() {
            $(this).dequeue().removeClass('__loading')
        })
    }

    $('.btn-filter-wrap').on('click', '.btn-filter', function(e) {
        var filter_data = $(this).data('filter');

        /* return if current */
        if($(this).hasClass('btn-active')) return;

        /* active current */
        $(this).addClass('btn-active').siblings().removeClass('btn-active');

        /* Filter */
        owl.owlFilter(filter_data, function(_owl) { 
            $(_owl).find('.item').each(owlAnimateFilter); 
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by creating javascript function

**JS Func**

```
function cat_detail(str) {

     document.getElementById("cat_detail").innerHTML = str;
    // alert(str);

}
```

After that i call event click on button and pass the string to the function.

```
<button  class="btn-filter" onclick="cat_detail('<?= $categorydetail ?>')" data-filter=".<?php echo $categoryclass; ?>"><?php echo $categoryname; ?></button>
```

and create a div with ID "cat_detail" which display the detail. :)